# Knockout js + Laravel localization

Tags: laravel, knockout.js, localization

Knockout JS includes some build-in validation messages such as

```
"This field is required" 
"Please enter at least {0} characters."
```

and so on.

How can I translate these messages ? If I just replace them with "@lang(..) or "trans(..)" it does not works..

Comment: Show your code. How do you currently attempt to use `@lang(..)` or `trans(..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I overrided and translated the knockout validation messages:

```
var = ko.observable().extend({required: {
        params: true,
        message: "@lang('errors.required_field')"
    }})
```

Comment: Please don't use the "answers" sections to make additions to your question. You can always edit your own question (in fact you can edit *any* question and answer on this site). It's best if you move the info to your question and delete this post.

Comment: This is not addition to the question, this is an answer. Setting "message" param to the observable and putting there the translation did the job.

Comment: All-right, never mind then. I did not see it that way at that point in time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not have build in functions for translations.

If you want to use messages in other languages you will have to add them to the [language files](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization#language-files).